# Root View Controller?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, self, uiwindow, sharekit

I'm working with `ShareKit`, an open-source sharing foundation for iOS apps. There is a known bug that prevents the Kit from detecting what your root view controller is. The fix for that bug is adding `[SHK setRootViewController:myViewController];` in the app delegate.

If the fix is in the `UIApplication didFinishLaunching` method, wouldn't the view controller just be `self`? What am I missing? I've also tried `self.viewController`, `self.window.rootViewController` and `self.window` to no avail.

**EDIT:** Here's the entire `didFinishLoading`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[Chatter_BoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Chatter_BoxViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [SHK setRootViewController:self.viewController];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it would only be "self" in the didFinishLaunching it would refer to the UIApplication, don't you agree? Are you initing correctly the viewController? Post some more code. :)

Comment to your Edit:

If you have your Window set normally in your XIB you don't need this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Also, if you do this (presuming your viewController is retained as property):

```
self.viewController = [[Chatter_BoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Chatter_BoxViewController" bundle:nil];
```

You will have a leak. Just do this:

```
viewController = [[Chatter_BoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Chatter_BoxViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Those are just the defaults in an iOS 5 view-based application, I have not changed them. Because of ARC in iOS 5, I don't have to worry about `self.viewController` leaking. I'm still wondering about the `[SHK]` line.